# How to take an exchange of comments on math.stackexchange.com to a chat exchange?

Tags: support, comment, user-interface, chat

I am baffled by the stack exchange user interface as regards chat. What do I do to take an exchange of comments on math.stackexchange.com to a chat exchange?

Comment: Before the automatic "move discussion to chat" link appears, or when it appears?

Comment: Before it appears - I am trying to be a good guy!

Comment: Then I think you need to create a chatroom for you and that user yourself - the other user needs 20 network reputation, or they won't be able to participate - and invite them. That doesn't copy the comments you two made so far to the chatroom, however, like the automated thing does. Waiting for the system to suggest chat has its upsides.

Comment: Of course, you can also copy the comments manually one by one. It might be useful to provide also some context to the conversation; in case someone gets to the room not from the particular question. (You get link to a comment simply by clicking on the timestamp.) For example like here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19743313#19743313

Comment: Re: "being a good guy": Imho, engaging in a discussion until the automated link appears is not necessarily a bad thing. Sure, comments are considered to be "low-level citizens" of the site, and excessive use of them might be frowned upon. A solution could be to wait for the link to appear, move the discussion to chat and then raise a custom flag on the question or answer (not the individual comments if I remember correctly) for moderator attention to remove the obsolete comments. This process would definitely qualify as a good guy's behavior in my book.

Comment: @Daniel x 2: Thanks! I will follow your advice and chat away till the automated thing happens.